# why border-image property requires an explicit border width as it already contains one and why max-height and border-color doesn't work as they should

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and trying to understand border-image property.i have four questions.

- max-width changes the width but max-height doesn't when i change its value
- when i change max-height to height it works fine
- why does border-color doesn't work as it comes after border-image property
- why i have to separately give border when i have given it in border-image property i.e 60px

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
  div{
  margin: 100px;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: solid blue;
  border-image: url("border_image.jpg") 74 /60px/ 4.5rem round;
  border-color: brown;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <p>This property is a shorthand for border-image-source, border-image- 
  slice, border-image-width, border-image-outset, and border-image-repeat. 
  As with all shorthand properties, any omitted sub-values will be set to 
  their initial value.</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Please split your question into two, one for max-height and one for border-image.

Comment: @BoltClock max-height is related with border-image cuz height property changes the dimensions of div i.e border-image but with max-height it doesn't. and i don't know what to post for max-height question separately